# How can I have a resizing sticky div between a non-sticky header and footer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

I'm trying to write a page where there must be a header and a footer with a body, all with unknown heights.

There must be a full scroll bar, which should shrink between the header and the footer whenever they're visible.

I've written a jsfiddle to demonstrate the issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/solidshook/xej43g0c/4/

I've made something close to what I need with a flexbox, which looks good but isn't quite what I want:

```
<div class='header'>
  i am the header
</div>
<div class='body'>
  <div class='sidebar'>
    <div class='sidebar-top'>
     top of sidebar
    </div>
    <div class='sidebar-bottom'>
     bottom of sidebar
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='content'>
    i am the content
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  i am the footer
</div>

 .body {
   display: flex;
 }

.content {
  width: 50%;
  height: 1000px;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 20%;
  align-self: flex-start;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

.sidebar-top {
   position:absolute;
   top: 0;
}

.sidebar-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.header, .footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
 }
 
}
```

I would really prefer to do this entirely with CSS, but if there's anything else to be done I'd be happy to see

Does anyone know how I could achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: _"There must be a full scroll bar, which should shrink between the header and the footer whenever they're visible."_ - can you please clarify that; do you want a "full" scrollbar (going over the full height of the browser window), or a scrollbar _just_ for the content element? And if the latter, what is supposed to happen, if the sidebar content also is to high to be shown completely between header and footer - does it get its own scrollbar then? Or should it scroll together with the content?

Comment: Yeah sure, I don't want a scrollbar going over just the content (if only, that would be much easier)

If the sidebar is too large, it would go into overflow and get it's own scrollbar yeah. The sidebar should fit the height of the viewable space between the header and the footer whilst being sticky, and the content should be whatever size it needs to be

Comment: If you want a scrollbar for the whole document, then you have little other choice but to position header and footer fixed, and give the content area sufficient padding at the top and bottom, so that all the content will be reachable without being overlapped at one end or the other. And since you can't know how much padding you will need, when the height of header and footer is unknown, you will have involve JavaScript to update the padding dynamically.

Comment: The header and footer can't be fixed because they have to be scrollable. I think the only unusual thing here is the sidebar, which is basically stretching to fit the viewable area. Trying to avoid JS because it can be a bit clunky on lower powered devices

Comment: _"The header and footer can't be fixed because they have to be scrollable."_ - okay, now I understand what you actually want, even less.

Comment: They need to move to fill the space between the header and the footer. If they're fixed, they wouldn't be between those two divs.
I really do think that the demo I provided with the Top of Sidebar and Bottom of Sidebar always being visible is the only way I can explain it